# Unable to use composite literal with map[string][]struct

Tags: go

I am trying to use composite literal with maps but unable to use it as it shows some error.

please find the code below.

I am a newbie to Golang and perhaps have some less understanding about composite literals.

```golang
type Assessment struct{
    StructuringForce map[string][]StructuringForce
}

type StructuringForce struct {
    Principles       map[string][]Capabilities
}

type Capability struct {
}

c1 := Capability{}

a1 := Assessment{

        StructuringForce : map[string][]StructuringForce{
            "Information Systems" , []StructuringForce{
                StructuringForce{
                    Principles : map[string][]Capabilities{
                        "Integration of IT Services" ,[]Capabilities{
                            c1,
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        },


    }
```

while constructing "a1" with composite literals I get "Missing key in map literals error".

But i can see that i have added keys.

Comment: "_I get syntax errors_" - which you need to include verbatim in your question.

Comment: You cannot use `make` together with literals. Just write the literal, no make.

Comment: @underscore_d - Please see the edited question. I have added the error line.

Comment: @Volker - please see the edited code.. I have removed make() and used just literals. still the issue is there

Comment: Map literals use `:` to separate key from value, not `,`. Please take the Tour of Go now (again) to get used to basic syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Volker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1266756/volker) pointed out, `make` cannot be used with literals. In your case it can either be:

```golang
make(map[string][]StructuringForce)
```

or

```golang
map[string][]StructuringForce{}{}
```

Secondly, for golang `map`, it's using `:` to separate the key-value, so it should be like:

```golang
a := map[string]string{
  "foo": "bar",
}
```

Thirdly, you don't have `Capabilities` defined, so I suppose you're trying to do `Capability`.

To sum up, the entire thing in the `main` func should look like:

```golang
c1 := Capability{}

a1 := Assessment{
        StructuringForce: map[string][]StructuringForce{
            "Information Systems": []StructuringForce{
                StructuringForce{
                    Principles: map[string][]Capability{
                        "Integration of IT Services": []Capabilities{
                            c1, // missing comma here as well
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    }
```

However, based on what you pasted, I would suggest you start from something straightforward to get started with the syntax and how to compose a `map`, like [Go By Examples](https://gobyexample.com/maps).

Another suggestion is that you can wrap the running code in `main` func when posting a SO question, which will make reproducing the issue a lot easier and more understandable to others who try to help.